# How to best convert tokens to enum in antlr4?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I have a grammar rule that looks like this:

```
expr : ENUMFILED IN '(' ENUMVALUE (',' ENUMVALUE)* ')' ;
ENUMFILED   :   'color' | 'food' | 'car';
ENUMVALUE   :   (ALPHANUMERIC)+;
DIGIT       :   '0'..'9' ;
LETTER      :   ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z');
ALPHANUMERIC:   (DIGIT | LETTER | '_');
```

So I can parse things like:

```
car in (ford,toyota)
color in (red,blue,green)
```

In code I then want to convert those values from the `in` clause to enums. For each group I have an Enum type, e.g.:

```
enum Car { FORD, TOYOTA, HONDA };
enum Color { RED, YELLOW, BLUE };
```

I will later walk the expression with a `ParseTreeWalker` many times so I want to convert the values to enums as I parse them. What's a good way of doing that?

Note that there is more to my grammar so I can have multiple occurrences of the same field in the input: e.g.  `car in (ford,toyota) .... car in (honda)`

Answer (score 0):

Best use a Map in the enum class:

```
public enum Car {
   TOYOTA( "Toyota" ), PORSCHE( "Porsche" ),...
   ...
   private static Map<String,Car> s2car;
   public static String transCar( String s ){
       return s2car.get( s );
   }
   Car( String s ){
        s2car.put(s,this);
   } 
}
```

Comment: Then in my BaseListener implementation I'd have to look this up by each token's .getText(), right? Is there a way to get the unique ID that each token has (so that each RED has the same ID) and I don't have to deal with strings? The idea in expr.tokens

Comment: How would that ever bridge the gap between "toyota" or "Toyota" and Car.TOYOTA?